# How to make the networking between the host and the target?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, operating-systems

I installed QNX IDE, Libraries and developemnt tool on Host system and QNX real time operating system is installed as a Target system : the target system runs the QNX Neutrino RTOS itself plus all the programs going to develop.

host operating system is windows or linux

How to make the networking between the host and the target ?? how to check the both machine is on the same network ??

I selected host on network on VM. (if i am using both host and target on the same computer)

I will select the bridge mode on VM (if i am using both host and target on the different computer)

If I ping from the host or the target : I am getting error as :

Destination Host unreachable.

Could anyone help me in this ??

Answer (score 0):

In virtualBox, the way to allow host and guest to be on the same network is to set up a Bridge connection. Before starting the VM, right click on it, then choose Network -> Adapter 1, and in the Panel that appears choose:

1) Check *Enable Network Adapter*;

2) Attached to: choose *Bridge Adapter*

3) Name: choose the interface your Host is currently using to connect to the Internet;

4) Click on Adavnced, then under *Promiscuous Mode*, choose *Allow VMs*.

There is nothing else to do. If it does not work, the fault will lie with:

1) your router, which may have further restrictions (like MAC filtering) enabled, which will prevent it from assigning an IP address to the VM;

2) your host, which has a firewall blocking connections not explicitly allowed.

3) your guest, which does not start correctly your network interfaces.

You will have to troubleshoot these three possible causes one by one, since the solution does depend upon the OSes used, the router brand and firmware, and so on.